# setCenter always ends near southpole

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm new at OpenLayers3 and trying to build a simple form that centers my map to a given spot. The problem is that i'm always landing somwhere near the south-pole. here is my code:

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0,0],
      zoom: 8
    })

    search.addEventListener("change", searchChanged);
    function searchChanged()
    {
        var searchVal = encodeURIComponent(search.value);
        var geocode = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?key=KEY&format=json&q=' + searchVal;

        $.getJSON(geocode, function(data)
            {
            if(!data)
                {
                return;
                }
            map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([data[0].lon, data[0].lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your coordinate will not be treated as string:

```
ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(data[0].lon), parseFloat(data[0].lat]), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
```

Better, debug it:

```
var coord = ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(data[0].lon), parseFloat(data[0].lat]), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
console.info(coord);
```